# What to name a SLIM file? .slim? .html.slim?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Sorry for such a silly question, but couldn't find it on the docs:

> filename.slim
>
> filename.html.slim

This seems like a really great language to work with.  I've used `HAML` before, so I think this will be a fairly nice transition.

Answer (score 15):

```
filename.html.slim
```

However, in the generic sense, it is

```
filename.response_type.rendering_engine
```

e.g.

```
index.xml.haml
index.rss.slim
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html.slim` would seem to be the convention used by the creator of [slim](https://github.com/slim-template). Though it seems to be a convention used across rails for view files, including `.html.haml` and `.html.erb` for example. The same convention is used for a lot of abstracted files like `.css.scss` and `.js.coffee`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `.html.slim` extension.

For example, if your layout template named just with `.slim` it will append not only for html response, but for js response too.

In this case, every time then you make jxh-request, you must set `layout false` for every js format response.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 7 with turbo/hotwire has an issue [1] with files that have just `.slim`, so I think it's better to stick with `.html.slim`

[1] - https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/287